# Do both NH2 groups in semicarbazide have the same properties?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Would it be correct to consider both the hydrazine and amide $\ce{-NH2}$ groups in semicarbazide (hydrazinecarboxamide) as derivatives of ammonia?

I thought about this possibility while writing the products obtained by reacting a carbonyl compound with semicarbazide. I was taught that only the hydrazine $\ce{-NH2}$ will be treated as a derivative of ammonia, so addition will take there and not at amide side.

Is there any possibility to add at amide? If not why?

[image: hydrazinecarboxamide]

Comment: Amide lone pair is delocalised into the C=O system (just google it), so it does not react with carbonyl compounds.

Comment: @orthocresol but at the same time, the amide hydrogen is more acidic because of conjugate base stabilization by resonance. Im not very sure about this. Can you please comment on it?

Comment: @DatBoi I don't see what the contradiction is?